# Tablayout , disable change between tabs with slide

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tablayout, pageviews

I made a TabLayout and it's work fine , but I want to disable change between tabs with slide and make it change tabs only by clicking the tab name
is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `TabLayout` *without* the `ViewPager`. In your `onTabSelected`, you load the view or fragment you want into the page container.